# How to make an R function to fill a column based off an if statement?

Tags: r

I have two columns of numeric values, I am trying to fill a new third column with the values of the initial two (since both of those have NAs). I would like to do an if statement to fill the third column with column A Unless column A is NA then use column B. If A and B have a value I want to fill the new col. with the grater value. Open to suggestions or help on original if else statement

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1)
df=data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,1:5),20,replace=T),nrow=10,ncol=2))

   X1 X2
1  NA NA
2   3  4
3  NA  4
4   1  1
5   4  5
6   2  5
7   5  1
8   1 NA
9   2  4
10  2  4

pmax(df$X1,df$X2,na.rm=T)
 [1] NA  4  4  1  5  5  5  1  4  4
```